# memory leak due to mat to IplImage* conversion Segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: opencv

I have a function as

```
void doCorrectIntensityVariation(Mat& image)
{   
            Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(19,19));
            Mat closed;
            morphologyEx(image, closed, MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);
            image.convertTo(image, CV_32F); // divide requires floating-point
            divide(image, closed, image, 1, CV_32F);
            normalize(image, image, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
            image.convertTo(image, CV_8UC1); // convert back to unsigned int
            imshow("gamma corrected",image); cvWaitKey(0);
```

}

and

```
IplImage* processImage(IplImage *imrgb, IplImage *n_im)
{
..................
..................
Mat pre(n_im);    
doCorrectIntensityVariation(pre);
n_im=new IplImage( pre);// this line throws segmentation fault (core dumped)
...............
...............
return n_im;
}
```

My program runs till last line 
But at the end throws
glibc detected *** : double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0886dee8 ***
 segmentation fault (core dumped) 
I have tried all the tricks I knew but I am stuck and dont know what is going wrong

Comment: The comments in your code contradict the description.  Does your program run correctly until exiting, where it crashes?  Or does it segfault when execution reaches the commented line?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but is there a good reason for mixing the C++ and C interface?

Comment: Sorry but I was unable to convert doCorrectIntensityVariation() function for IplImage* , could you please do that for me.